# How can I change the viewable area of my external display?

Tags: mac, display, accessibility

I dropped my external monitor and its top left corner is cracked. I no longer can see the top left section of my monitor. It's pixelated. If I'm in full-screen mode, I can't see this reigon of my monitor

[image]

Is there a way to **shift everything away from the left side of my monitor**? Or is some other useful hack or accessibility feature for my situation?

I've already adjust the Hover Text feature and bumped Text Size to 90pt and moved the location to bottom right, but wondering if there is any other solution.

[image]

Comment: This gets asked frequently. The answer is invariably, "No".

Comment: @Tetsujin that's a fair answer. Can you link any previous asked questions? I just searched again but couldn't fine similar questions.

Comment: My google-fu fails me :\ They're under such disparate wordings I can't track one down.

Comment: I found what I think is the primary Q&A on this topic.